# Want to parse few properties as JSON object and other as normal

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-core

Is it possible to parse a few properties as JSON object only? Something like this.

```
public class Request{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public JObject? Address { get; set; }
    public List<JObject> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

```
Request JSON could look like
{
    "Title":"My title",
    "Address":{
        "property1":1
        "property2":2
    },
    "Addresses":[
    {
        "property1":1
        "property2":2
    },
    {
        "property1":1
        "property2":2
    }
    ]
}
```

By making the JSON properties as string and sending the stringify JSON we can achieve this. But that is something I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Is `Request` supposed to be a class?

Comment: Yes, I will edit and update the question.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid either. I like to use [this](https://jsonlint.com/) site to validate JSON.

Comment: Works as expected: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ME2Bpz

Comment: I'm implementing it for API. After adding [FromBody] it was able to parse it. Even though there's a similar API I created for testing with different request model that do not have JObject. It worked without this attribute [FromBody]. Looks like [FromBody] is required for this case.